# Checkboxlist ng-repeat filter dynamic angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, checkboxlist

I am trying in AngularJS to display the employee details with dynamic filter  (Location - Value like US, IN, CA etc..) as checkboxlist based on the data got it from DB. I have tried multiple ways without success. Please help to achive the dynamic filter from Checkboxlist.

My code sample below:

```
  <html>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myController">


     <div >Location</div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="empL in EmpResult | unique : 'Location'">
                    <td>
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="loc" value={{empL.Location}} />
                            {{empL.Location}}
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table align="left" style="width: 100%" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th align="left" style="width: 30%">Employee</th>
                <th align="left" style="width: 20%">Address</th>
                <th align="left" style="width: 15%">Location</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="empN in EmpResult | filter : loc">

                <td align="left" style="width: 30%">{{empN.EmpName}}</td>
                <td align="left" style="width: 10%">{{empN.Address}}</td>
                <td align="left" style="width: 15%">{{empN.Location}}</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.unique'])
        .controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {

            $http({
                method: 'Get',
                params: { strName: $scope.strName },
                url: 'Emp.asmx/GetEmpbyName'
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.EmpResult = response.data;
            })

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, filters do not work that way. You have to define an actual filter method (not just using a scope variable the way you are doing). Check the documentation. Here you have a good description and very simple example that quite matches your needs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: @FDavidov that's true but the filter that @Ravi is using comes from the dependency `'ui.unique'` that he have injected in his module and so it needs not to be defined. However this dependency is depreciated, so my question is why to use a depreciated dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a mirror of your issue, please take a look at it. I think it should work in your situation.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v4PgnZJREZILPmZ9rNZn?p=preview)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
      <script>
          document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
      </script>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
      <div ng-init="init()">Location</div>
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="empL in locations">
                  <td>
                      <span>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="locations + $index" data-ng-model="locChkBox.loc[$index]" ng-true-value="'{{empL}}'" ng-false-value="" ng-change="repopulate()"/>
                              {{empL}}
                      </span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <table align="left" style="width: 100%" class="table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th align="left" style="width: 30%">Employee</th>
                  <th align="left" style="width: 20%">Address</th>
                  <th align="left" style="width: 15%">Location</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="empN in EmpResult | filter : locFilter ">
  
                  <td align="left" style="width: 30%">{{empN.EmpName}}</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 10%">{{empN.Address}}</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 15%">{{empN.Location}}</td>
  
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
      
      myApp.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
      
          $scope.locations = [];
          $scope.search = {};
          $scope.locChkBox = {};
          $scope.locChkBox.loc = [];
          $scope.locChkBox.loc.push("US");
      
          $scope.init = function() {
              $scope.EmpResult = JSON.parse('[{"EmpName":"jondoe","Address":"dummyAddr","Location":"US"},{"EmpName":"jondoe2","Address":"dummyAddr2","Location":"IN"},{"EmpName":"jondoe3","Address":"dummyAddr3","Location":"CA"},{"EmpName":"jondoe4","Address":"dummyAddr4","Location":"US"},{"EmpName":"jondoe5","Address":"dummyAddr5","Location":"IN"},{"EmpName":"jondoe6","Address":"dummyAddr6","Location":"CA"},{"EmpName":"jondoe7","Address":"dummyAddr7","Location":"US"},{"EmpName":"jondoe8","Address":"dummyAddr8","Location":"IN"},{"EmpName":"jondoe9","Address":"dummyAddr9","Location":"CA"},{"EmpName":"jondoe11","Address":"dummyAddr11","Location":"US"},{"EmpName":"jondoe22","Address":"dummyAddr22","Location":"IN"}]');
      
              var flags = [],
                  output = [],
                  l = $scope.EmpResult.length,
                  i;
              for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                  if (flags[$scope.EmpResult[i].Location]) continue;
                  flags[$scope.EmpResult[i].Location] = true;
                  output.push($scope.EmpResult[i].Location);
              }
      
              $scope.locations = output;
      
          };
      
          $scope.locFilter = function(item) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.locChkBox.loc.length; i++) {
              if (item.Location === $scope.locChkBox.loc[i])
                  return true;
            }
            return false;
          };
      }]);
    </script>
  
  </body>

</html>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

This code will display all the values if none of the checkbox is selected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
      <script>
          document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
      </script>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
      <div ng-init="init()">Location</div>
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="empL in locations">
                  <td>
                      <span>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="locations + $index" data-ng-model="locChkBox.loc[$index]" ng-true-value="'{{empL}}'" ng-false-value="" ng-change="repopulate()"/>
                              {{empL}}
                      </span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <table align="left" style="width: 100%" class="table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th align="left" style="width: 30%">Employee</th>
                  <th align="left" style="width: 20%">Address</th>
                  <th align="left" style="width: 15%">Location</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="empN in EmpResult | filter : locFilter ">
  
                  <td align="left" style="width: 30%">{{empN.EmpName}}</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 10%">{{empN.Address}}</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 15%">{{empN.Location}}</td>
  
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
      
      myApp.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
      
          $scope.locations = [];
          $scope.search = {};
          $scope.locChkBox = {};
          $scope.locChkBox.loc = [];
      
          $scope.init = function() {
              $scope.EmpResult = JSON.parse('[{"EmpName":"jondoe","Address":"dummyAddr","Location":"US"},{"EmpName":"jondoe2","Address":"dummyAddr2","Location":"IN"},{"EmpName":"jondoe3","Address":"dummyAddr3","Location":"CA"},{"EmpName":"jondoe4","Address":"dummyAddr4","Location":"US"},{"EmpName":"jondoe5","Address":"dummyAddr5","Location":"IN"},{"EmpName":"jondoe6","Address":"dummyAddr6","Location":"CA"},{"EmpName":"jondoe7","Address":"dummyAddr7","Location":"US"},{"EmpName":"jondoe8","Address":"dummyAddr8","Location":"IN"},{"EmpName":"jondoe9","Address":"dummyAddr9","Location":"CA"},{"EmpName":"jondoe11","Address":"dummyAddr11","Location":"US"},{"EmpName":"jondoe22","Address":"dummyAddr22","Location":"IN"}]');
      
              var flags = [],
                  output = [],
                  l = $scope.EmpResult.length,
                  i;
              for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                  if (flags[$scope.EmpResult[i].Location]) continue;
                  flags[$scope.EmpResult[i].Location] = true;
                  output.push($scope.EmpResult[i].Location);
              }
      
              $scope.locations = output;
      
          };
      
          $scope.locFilter = function(item) {
            if($scope.locChkBox.loc.isNull()) return true;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.locChkBox.loc.length; i++) {
              if (item.Location === $scope.locChkBox.loc[i])
                  return true;
            }
            return false;
          };
      }]);
      
      Array.prototype.isNull = function (){
          return this.join().replace(/,/g,'').length === 0;
      };
    </script>
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: when i have revamped the code, I made the mistake but in my actual code have the ng-app and ng-controller in body tag.

Comment: thanks for your code it is working for me but by default it is filtering out by Location as "US" but on initial load, I want to display all records without any filter. Also the filter is working without ng-change="repopulate()"

Comment: Hi @Ravi , Please see my updated `EDIT2` code. This code will show all the results if none of the checkbox is selected and if any of them is selected, then it will display results according to that.

Comment: Hi @Raman,  thanks for your quick response. it is working as I expected. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr ng-repeat="empN in EmpResult | filter : 'loc'">
```

Use the filter with single quotes also. This will filter the data from checkbox.